# Change of basis for reflection across a line

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations, change-of-basis

I am asked to find the expression for reflection about the line $y=mx$. First, I wrote down the reflection matrix about the x-axis in the standard basis:

\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & -1
\end{pmatrix}

Then I wrote down the rotation matrix to get from the standard to rotated frame:

\begin{pmatrix}
\cos \theta & \sin \theta \\
- \sin \theta & \cos \theta
\end{pmatrix}

but now writing this in terms of $m$ we have

\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{1}{\sqrt{1 + m^2}} & \frac{m}{\sqrt{1 + m^2}} \\
- \frac{m}{\sqrt{1 + m^2}} & \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 + m^2}}
\end{pmatrix}

so total we have

\begin{gather*}
\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{1}{\sqrt{1 + m^2}} & \frac{m}{\sqrt{1 + m^2}} \\
- \frac{m}{\sqrt{1 + m^2}} & \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 + m^2}}
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & -1
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{1}{\sqrt{1 + m^2}} & \frac{m}{\sqrt{1 + m^2}} \\
- \frac{m}{\sqrt{1 + m^2}} & \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 + m^2}}
\end{pmatrix}^{-1}
\end{gather*}

But the answer first picks $\{(1,m), (-m,1)\}$ as a basis for the new frame and calculates the change of basis matrices as

\begin{pmatrix}
1 & -m \\
m & 1
\end{pmatrix}

and

\begin{gather*}
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & -m \\
m & 1
\end{pmatrix}^{-1} 
= 
\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{1}{1+m^2} & \frac{m}{1+m^2} \\
-\frac{m}{1+m^2} & \frac{1}{1+m^2}
\end{pmatrix}
\end{gather*}

I understand the method they used, but I don't understand why the first method doesn't give the same answer. There is a square root that shouldn't be there.

Comment: Two things: first, your rotation matrix has the $-$ sign on the wrong $\sin\theta$ term. Second, their new basis is not normalized (they rotate and scale): if you normalize from the beginning (divide by the determinant), you'll get the same result. In this application, normalization is not important since you have both the matrix and its inverse as terms of the product that represents the reflection.

Comment: @dvdgrgrtt Thanks so much, I thought I was going crazy